# Cannot access another site after log-in with requests.session

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

this is my first question here and i am really new to programming aswell, so please consider that while answering :)

I am trying to create a webscraper via python with "BeautifulSoup" and "requests" for the fantasy bundesliga game, where i want to collect all the player data.
I think I already managed to log in to the site, but i am not doing it correctly.
I create a Session and send a payload with my log in information. Afterwards I want do whatever I like there in different pages that require a logged in user. But i always get redirected to the Homepage.

The normal Login Page is https://fantasy.bundesliga.de/?register_or_login=login .
With the Developer Tools I found the right url to simulate the login as "https://accounts.eu1.gigya.com/accounts.login". The form data has many parameters and I am not sure how to manipulate them correctly. In a first try I simply copied the parameters from a manual log in.
But when I try to access another website it redirects me to the Homepage "https://fantasy.bundesliga.de/".

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {"loginID": "replace with E-Mail",
"password": "replace with password",
"sessionExpiration": "0",
"targetEnv": "jssdk",
"include": "profile,data,emails,subscriptions,preferences,",
"includeUserInfo": "true",
"loginMode": "standard",
"lang": "de",
"APIKey": "3_2B6SeL1zQuVojVM9IlfzLovH7xJLlpUIeSXNPMS0uihudZQtuKy99SfKcrJRtWKo",
"source": "showScreenSet",
"sdk": "js_latest",
"authMode": "cookie",
"pageURL": "https://fantasy.bundesliga.de/",
"format": "json",
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post("https://accounts.eu1.gigya.com/accounts.login", data = payload)
    print(p.url)
    f = open("login.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    f.write(p.text)
    f.close()
    r = s.get("https://fantasy.bundesliga.de/match_days/14/lineups/252439")
    print(r.url)
```

login.txt contains all my profile information so i have succesfully logged in.
However the last line, where i want to print r.url, the output is "https://fantasy.bundesliga.de/" and so i cannot reach the information i want.

I am honestly clueless, because I could not find this problem online. Everybody seems to access their pages successfully after they logged in.

Thanks to everybody answering!

Comment: I think you are missing something in the payload

Comment: Thanks for answering! I already logged in successfully as i said, so I dont think anything is missing. The problem only occures when I want to reach another page AFTER the Log In.

Comment: hi @JanH. Can you confirm you have the required authorization/rights to access the resources you're trying to access?

Comment: Hello @suo ! The link is perfectly accessable, when i do it manually. So yes, i have the authorization/rights for that link. I also tried other links, but I always get redirected to the Homepage....